# How do i return rows with specific value if else?

Tags: sql, laravel

I want my query to return the rows of the table where a column contains a specific value first, and then order by specific created date.

If I have a table something like this example:

```
      - Table: Position
      - id - position_value -  created_at
      - 1    1                 2014-07-3
      - 2    1                 2014-07-3
      - 3    1                 2014-07-4
      - 4    2                 2014-07-4
      - 5    2                 2014-07-5
      - 6    2                 2014-07-5
```

And using that table I want to my query to return the rows which contain position 1, and then created date desc. But rows contain position 2 created date ascending.

i already using this query on laravel

```
Position::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD('1', '2')'),asc)->orderBy('created_at',desc)->paginate(29);
```

but it only return with all position 1,2 and created_at desc, i want position = 1 created_at asc and then position = 2 created_at desc. Is this possible to do using only one query?

thanks

---------------------------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------------------

```
$position = Position::orderBy(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END desc)'))->get();
```

This works just fine, but i need "->paginate(29)", and "Field(1,2)", can someone update the answer please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will help you

```
SELECT * FROM Position ORDER BY 
CASE  WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END ASC,
CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END DESC
```

Comment: can someone try to convert this query to laravel please?

Comment: this query DB::raw('FIELD('1', '2')'),asc is gone in your syntax, can you help me with inserting field to those syntax?